# Smooth kinetic scrolling in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, scroll, touch

I'm developing a game for mobile platforms. I have a menu with levels. There are a lot of levels so there should be kinetic scrolling. What did I do - every frame I read `touches[0].position` and based and difference between previous position I move camera. 
But, because of the inaccurate touch position (I suppose so) the camera doesn't move smoothly. I'm thinking about calculate average speed for three frames for example and move camera according to speed. Can you give me any advice how to smooth movement?

Also, `touches[0].deltaPosition` seems to work incorrect.

Comment: "seems to work incorrect" is not a problem description

Comment: I meant that result of 'touches[0].deltaPosition' is different from result of subtraction 'touches[0].position' from previous touch position.